# Написание скрипта

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток!
Возникла проблема с написанием скрипта для исполнения java программы на кластере
У меня есть проект в eclipse, делаю из него jar.
Вот пример скрипта, который написал(не работает):

```
#!/bin/sh 
/home/m/test/Test4.jar
```

Кроме того, у проекта есть еще и сторонние библиотеки, которые я не знаю как включить в скрипт..

Comment: Комментарии к моему ответу закончились, так что напишу здесь.

Вы меня совсем запутали. Если программа написана на OpenMP, она выполняется не на кластере, а в нескольких потоках одной машины. Если же вы её выполняли на кластере, то тот скрипт, который вы привели, к запуску программы на нескольких машинах не имеет вообще никакого отношения. Давайте определимся с терминами, в которых мы общаемся.

Comment: Программу, написанную на OpenMP можно выполнять и на кластере. Скрипт привел как запуск программы, а количество узлов и задействованных ядер уже непосредственно через команду в командной строке, т.е. например так:      
> qsub -l nodes=5:ppn=4 hello.run  (5 узлов и 4 процесса на каждом из узлов)

Comment: Есть контакт! Теперь мы поняли, что программа не просто так работала на кластере - она работала под OpenMP! Теперь осталось осознать, что программа на Java не будет просто так работать на кластере - ей тоже нужно нечто вроде OpenMP. В случае с Java это JOMP, JPPF, Hadoop. Ну, или велосипедостроение с копированием программы на все машины кластера и ручная раздача задач каждой машине.

Comment: именно, добавил ответ. Осталась последняя проблема - как добавить сторонние библиотеки

Answer (score 3):

Jar-файл сам по себе не является исполняемым. Для запуска нужна JRE. Запуск jar-файла из командной строки выглядит так:

```
java -classpath /путь/к/сторонним/библиотекам/ -jar Test4.jar
```

Comment: Какая разница на чем запускать?

Comment: попробуйте такой скрипт, пол года думал, может получится:
!/bin/sh
java -jar /home/m/test/Test4.jar

Comment: Если выполнение должно проходить на вычислительном кластере, то стандартными средствами ОС и Java тут не обойтись. Почитайте про [Hadoop][1].

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadoop

Comment: @fori1ton, но программу на с++ на том де кластере умею запускать...     
Неужели есть разница, что именно запускать?

Comment: А как вы эту программу на C++ запускали на кластере? Просто вызывая её в командной строке? Тогда спешу вас огорчить - она исполнялась только на компьютере, на котором вы её запустили.

Comment: Нет, программу запускал с помощью скрипта, предварительно скопировав исходники на кластере (указывая число узлов и ядер на каждом из узлов
)

Comment: Скрипт в студию!

Comment: Вот например для запуска OpenMP программы скрипт был такой:
>#!/bin/sh 
> /home/sol/openmp/hello

Comment: То есть вы вот этот скрипт вместе с программой вручную копировали на все машины кластера и вручную запускали его на каждой машине? Вашему упорству можно только позавидовать. Можете сделать то же самое с вашей java-программой. Не забудьте, что JRE должна стоять на каждой машине кластера. А можете перестать изобретать велосипед и воспользоваться готовым решением. Для Java - Hadoop, для C и прочих компилируемых языков - OpenMPI.

Comment: А с чего взяли что я копировал на все машины то?      
Скопировал скрип и исходник на головную, дальше через командную строку запустил на нужном числе машин

Answer (score 0):

Все-таки одну проблему решил: смог запустить с помощью скрипта, вот он:

```
#!/bin/sh 
export LIBJARS=/home/m/joda-time-2.2.jar
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/home/m/joda-time-2.2.jar
hadoop jar /home/m/testing.jar test/Test4 -libjars {LIBJARS}
```

Осталось понять как решить проблему с подключаемыми библиотеками

Comment: Проблема с подключаемыми библиотеками решается опцией libjars:

    hadoop jar /home/mikhailyuk/testing.jar test/Test4 -libjars ВАШИ_БИБЛИОТЕКИ

Comment: Вот [статья][1], описывающая сразу три способа подключения сторонних библиотек. Вот [официальная документация][2], описывающая опции командной сроки Hadoop. Вот [Google][3], в котором вы всё это могли найти за пять минут.

  [1]: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/
  [2]: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/commands_manual.html
  [3]: http://google.com/

Comment: Да я вот как раз и читал вот эту статью: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/
Следую 1-му способу, почему-то не запускается..   Правильно ли я понимаю, что библиотеку нужно расположить на узле и “-libjars” указать полный путь до нее?

Comment: Вот пример:
> #!/bin/sh 
hadoop jar /home/mikhailyuk/testing.jar test/Test4 -libjars /home/mikhailyuk/joda-time-2.2.jar

Comment: Вроде не на узле, а на сервере. Там написано, что такая библиотека попадает в распределённый кэш и становится доступна всем узлам.

Comment: Библиотека на головной машине, путь до нее прописан в скрипте...    
А второй способ заключается в том, чтобы поместить библиотеку в подкаталог lib? тоже делал, но результата нет

Comment: Насколько я понял, опция libjars может рассматриваться как параметр, передаваемый в вашу программу. Для того, чтобы Hadoop рассматривал его как параметр, переданный ему, нужно сделать, как описывается в [этой статье][1].

  [1]: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/using-libjars-option-hadoop

Comment: Вроде заработало, скрипт обновил